# Jqgrid compatability with Jquery and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jqgrid

Is jqgrid 4.6.0 version compatible with  jQuery 3.4.1 , jQuery UI 1.11.4 i and bootstrap v 4.3.1?

We tried to use it and most of UI controls is having some issue with rendering.
Please suggest if we are following right approach or do we have to upgrade jqgrid to use the latest stack?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of jqGrid is not compatible with specified jQuery and jQuery UI. The 4.6 version of jqGrid is 5 year old and is no more supported. It is a good idea to consider upgrade to a supported version.

You can select commercial [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) with guaranteed support and [known developing vision](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103317)  or you can consider [free-jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which provide only basic support without any future development and clear vision on what will be developed.